# Which Wordpress template does the posts page use as standard?

Tags: wordpress

I'm just wondering which page template the standard blog posts use. 
I am using the Roots.io theme and I don't have blog posts on the home page, I have them on a page called 'news' - I just wondered which template file this will use, or what I will need to create, as I can't seem to find which template it is using, so I can modify it. I have checked the hierarchy. they are not custom post types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a peek [inside of the templates directory](https://github.com/roots/roots/tree/master/templates) you will see the list of included templates for the roots theme. For styling pages and posts use the content-*.php files.

Comment: The blog overview page uses the 'content.php' page, whereas an individual blog uses 'content-single.php'.